# Open chromedriver in normal mode (no incognito) in selenium python in linux ubuntu?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, ubuntu

When I try to open chromedriver with selenium, the browser starts in incognito mode, but I need my default profile to load my cookies. I'm trying this code but it doesn't work:

```
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=/home/my_name/.config/google-chrome/Default') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"/home/hackangel91/Desktop/bot_amazon/chromedriver", options=options)
driver.get("url")
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: now it work in Default profile but the other commands doest't work, why?

Comment: i need to make an autologin